# How to speed up Pandas DataFrame calculation of divided a constant?

Tags: python, pandas

I line_profile my function, and find the bottleneck is below line, which divide the columns value of a dataframe `df` by 100 :

```
df.iloc[:,2:6] = df.iloc[:,2:6]/100.0
```

Any tip to speed it up ?

Comment: %timeit df.values[:, 2:6]*0.01
1 loops, best of 3: 366 ms per loop

%timeit df.iloc[:, 2:6]*0.01
1 loops, best of 3: 187 ms per loop

Answer (score 1):

My timings:

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 10000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(N,7)), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))
print (df)

In [79]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 2:6].div(100)
1 loop, best of 3: 221 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 2:6] / 100
1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 2:6] / 100.0
1 loop, best of 3: 205 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 2:6] * 0.01
1 loop, best of 3: 180 ms per loop
```

Comment: No significant difference. I am looking for at least 50% less time